# Check if compression is done

Tags: c#, zip

I am trying whole day to figure out how to get if compression is done. My current code is below:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
    zip.AddDirectory(ApplicationData);
    zip.Save(AppData + "MagazaContent.mea");
    Directory.Delete(ApplicationData, true);
}
```

I want to trigger `Directory.Delete(ApplicationData, true);` when the compression is done. With my current code, `Directory.Delete(ApplicationData, true);` gets triggered before it's compressed. How can I do this? Please help.

**Edit: I updated my question with working code**

```
public class ZipSaver
{
    private ZipFile _zipFile;

    public ZipSaver()
    { 
        _zipFile = new ZipFile();
        _zipFile.SaveProgress += ZipFile_SaveProgress;
    } 

    public void StartZippingFile()
    {
        _zipFile.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
        _zipFile.AddDirectory(frmMain.ApplicationData);
        _zipFile.Save(frmMain.AppData + "MagazaContent.mea");
    }

    public void ZipFile_SaveProgress(object sender, SaveProgressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.EventType == ZipProgressEventType.Saving_Completed)
        {
            Directory.Delete(frmMain.ApplicationData, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if you were to remove the the `Directory.Delete(ApplicationData, true);` outside of the using..

Comment: For the life of me I can't find the ZipFile class you're using. The ZipFile class documented in the MSDN is a static class.

Comment: Tried, not working. I am getting `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` on `zip.AddDirectory(ApplicationData);`. @dj-kraze

Comment: This is ZipDotNet @zmbq

Comment: where is ApplicationData originally defined perhaps you need to move it out side of the scope of the method declaration also how come you are not using windows built in Compression that comes with .net..? I use it and it works perfectly..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I tried the Windows Built-in compression, but still had the same problem. It's a string that's reffering to a folder inside %appdata%.

Comment: can you show the full string.. perhaps you need to use a literal path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using the [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx).

We'll need to know which `ZipFile` you're referring to.

In the mean time, you might look at the events on the class (if it has any) to see if there is something `OnZipCompleted` or even an `Async` version that you could possibly await.

Edit: Looks like the ZipFile has an `OnSaveCompleted` event.
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Zip/ZipFile.Events.cs

You could do something like this:

```
public class ZipSaver
{
 private ZipFile _zipFile;

 public ZipSaver() // add necessary parameters
 { 
    _zipFile = new ZipFile();
    _zipFile.OnSaveCompleted += ZipFile_OnSaveCompleted;
 } 

 public void StartZippingFile()
 { 
 // pretty much the code you have in your question with the exception of the using block around it.
 } 

 public void ZipFile_OnSaveCompleted() // Add necessary parameters from OnSaveCompleted delegate
 {
 // Delete application data 
 // Dispose of ZipFile.
 }
}
```

Hopefully that helps you out.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using ZipDotNet library for this.

Comment: I can't seem to find `OnSaveCompleted` event in `ZipFile`.

Comment: I edited my question with your code but I modified it a little. It works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my last answer was not in context
here's an example

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
zip.SaveProgress += delegate { Directory.Delete(ApplicationData, true); };
zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;
zip.AddDirectory(ApplicationData);
zip.Save(AppData + "MagazaContent.mea");
```

In this case you can not use "using" on the ZipFile class and you will have to dispose it yourself since otherwise you will make a raise condition and will try to invoke an event (SaveProgress) on disposed object.

Comment: You are right, the question was about the saving not the extract part. I see from the code that there is an event for saving complete called SaveProgress

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the source code](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Zip/ZipFile.Events.cs), there's a `SaveProgress` event handler. You can hook into that and see when the save is done.

I didn't notice multithreading in the source I looked at, so I don't understand why Save doesn't return after the file is saved. I guess I missed something.

Comment: I saw that there's a `SaveProgress` event handler, but I have no idea how to implement it in an already created method.